# python beginner:What goes wrong with 'print mystr.split(',').sort(reverse=True)'

Tags: python

I try to sort a sequence of number from a string:

In python interpreter:

```
    >>> mystr = '1,2,3,4,5'
    >>> a = mystr.split(',')
    >>> a
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
    >>> a.sort(reverse=True)
    >>> a
    ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

But when I want to make the code shorter,problem occures:

```
    >>> mystr
    '1,2,3,4,5'
    >>> print mystr.split(',').sort(reverse=True)
    None
```

Why does that happen?Hope for your help!

Answer (score 6):

The [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) doesn't return a new list, rather it sorts the list on which the function is called

More accurately, `sort()` does an in-place sorting of the list

```
>>> a = mystr.split(',')
>>> a.sort(reverse=True) # Nothing is returned at this line
>>> a # But the list is sorted
['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

---

If you want to return sorted list, use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function instead

```
>>> sorted(mystr.split(','), reverse=True)
['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

---

**Side Note :** The `sort` vs `sorted` can lead to a detailed discussion on efficiency of the in-place sorting algorithms. Since the `sort` function doesn't create a new list, it will be more memory efficient than the `sorted`. Also `sort` would be able to handle larger lists.

Comment: Might be good to point out that `.sort()` is more efficient than `sorted()`, though there's no need to worry about it for small lists and/or infrequent sorts.

Answer (score 0):

To chain it together like you want to, you could do:

```
mystr = '1,2,3,4,5'
print list(reversed(mystr.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want in one chain:

```
sorted('1,2,3,4,5'.split(','))[::-1]  # ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, sorted() vs sort() to return a list vs modifying in place, here is a link to read up on it:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

```
print sorted(mystr.split(','), reverse=True)
```